# Upgrade Windows 10 to 11 with ISO and apply Autounattend.xml

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, upgrade, sysprep, unattended

I want to upgrade a bunch of Windows 10 PCs with a customized Windows 11 ISO. Usually I pass some settings using `autounattend.xml` which I put in the ISOs root directory. So far so good, installing W11 fresh works as intended, `autounattend.xml` gets applied.

Now when I start an upgrade from within a booted Windows 10 using the mounted ISO and run `sources\setupprep.exe`, this `autounattend.xml` does not get applied. This especially results in an OOBE-Screen where the user gets asked about location services, find my device and so on. Basically things that `<ProtectYourPC>3</ProtectYourPC>` should block are now asked to the user.

Does anyone know how I can make to following `autounattend.xml` get applied to an upgraded installation?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State">
  <settings pass="oobeSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
      <OOBE>
        <ProtectYourPC>3</ProtectYourPC>
        <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
        <HideOnlineAccountScreens>true</HideOnlineAccountScreens>
        <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
      </OOBE>
    </component>
  </settings>
</unattend>
```

I've tried putting the XML in the following locations within the `install.wim`, without success:

- ```bash
  # Root directory:
  .\Autounattend.xml
  ```
- ```
  Windows\System32\Sysprep\Autounattend.xml
  ```
- ```
  Windows\Panther\Unattend\Autounattend.xml
  ```
- ```bash
  path\to\custom\directory\Autounattend.xml

  # and:
  HKLM\System\Setup!UnattendFile
  ```

Comment: Have you tried placing the answer file within the `install.wim` at `Windows\Panther\unattend.xml`? _(There is a double `windows` directory typo on the [man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/update-windows-settings-and-scripts-create-your-own-answer-file-sxs#add-the-answer-file-and-script-to-the-image))_

Comment: See https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/96683-create-media-automated-unattended-install-windows-10-a.html

Comment: It looks like the installer ignores unattend files when you run the setup from within a booted windows 10. If you boot to the ISO, you can specify a location to the windows installer setup, like: `Setup /Unattend:D:\path\to\unattend.xml`. You can also include it as a parameter in a `setupconfig.ini` file. Importing it into the .wim should work either way

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to put `Autounattend.xml` inside the `install.wim` within at:

```
Windows\System32\Sysprep\Unattend.xml
```

The key factor was to rename the file for this specific case from `Autounattend.xml` to `Unattend.xml`. This is documented on many sites, but it is easy to skip this detail, and I used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-automation-overview) site to find the solution